# Particles collision margin/padding

Tags: mesh, particles, physics, collision

I am making a simulation with boids particles inside a mesh (I have applied collision physics to the mesh, inverted the normals and applied all transformations) and for some reason, the particles do not collide to the edge of the mesh and leave a gap from all sides.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally. I had changed the scale from default 0.05 to 1. If I change it back to 0.05, it seems to work. Don’t know why though.

[image]